# Choose between adopting ASP.NET Identity and custom entity models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

By adopting ASP.NET Identity, I mean we reuse as many parts of it as possible including the `IdentityDbContext` and the related built-in models such as `IdentityUser`, `IdentityUserClaim`, ...

However when writing code with `Entity Framework` or even with any other frameworks, we commonly have our own `BaseEntity` class as the root of all other entities although it may even be empty, but in future we may need to add some common properties later.

So I've found that those 2 things cannot live together, I prefer to have a `BaseEntity` class but still re-using the ASP.NET Identity has its own benefit.

What would you do in this case? I have a feeling that the ASP.NET Identity has something faulted in design, it's not perfect and makes me confused while choosing the approach to go (when we have just one choice we can take it easy but when we have some choices we may need several days to evaluate and weight before ending up with the final hard decision).

Comment: You can use different entity models with ASP.NET Identity. ASP.NET Identity is the authentication service, not the entity model.

Comment: BTW using a `BaseEntity` just in case you need to add something isn't a good idea. Inheritance is an `is a` relationship and abusing it easily leads to trouble. In this case it makes it *harder* to add new properties as it adds a hard-coded relation between unrelated entities and any change affects *all* of them.

Comment: On the last project I was on, all the entities except identity ones were based on a BaseIdentity.  That being said, the only things in baseIdentity were the key and a 'last updated' field, so only simple stuff.

Comment: Extending an existing class *doesn't* need inheritance anyway. Using composition is far more flexible. Extension methods can also help. With ORMs, there are *many* ways to add eg standardized mappings

Comment: @Neil in this case, what was the point of this anemic object? BTW that's the name of an antipattern. You could have used an interface instead without introducing the hard relation. You wouldn't have to explicitly tell EF to *not* try to store the inheritance relation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To save duplicating code and properties.  It originally was an interface, but then every class ended up implementing the exact same properties (but with the potential of slightly different implementations).

Comment: Actually using deep inheritance is not good, but just 1 level of inheritance is fine, I think. As Neil said, my purpose of using `BaseEntity` class here is just for some common properties like Id, last modified date, ... EF supports flattening those common properties into each derived table (TPC or Table Per Concrete Type), I've not encountered any trouble while using inheritance in my models (just 1 level to reduce unnecessary complexity).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you said this *ASP.NET Identity is the authentication service, not the entity model* but really I don't agree with you on that point, it still includes its built-in  entity model system and to adopt that framework completely, you must use its models and work with Entity Framework (of course). Of course if we don't use its models, we can still take benefit of its remaining advantage of authentication.

Comment: In other words, you don't like Identity because it uses its own base class, only it calls it `IdentityUser` instead of `BaseEntity`. In *Identity's* case though the relationship is critical, derived classes *are* IdentityUser objects. Furthermore, those are *Identity's* classes, not your own. You can map them to any table you want, add any extra functionality you want through the EF model. The *classes* though are part of Identity's API.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the `BaseEntity` I mean here is used as root class for all entities, while `IdentityUser` is not for that purpose, of course I can extend my own custom identity user from `IdentityUser`, but it's just for user, not for other entities. Unless we use 2 different contexts, one for just identities, one for the rest (the main business entities), looks like that's one possible approach to go.